# Autologin for ubuntu (Yocto image)

Tags: autologin, yocto

Can anyone please help me in finding out how to setup auto login for ubuntu having yocto image?
Do I need to make any change in any of the recipes or any of the file in /etc/init.d/.. or similar file?
By auto login I mean avoiding logging prompt after booting up.

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Do you want to have autologin in an image created by Yocto, or do you want autologin on the Ubuntu machine? (In the former case, what's the relationship to Ubuntu in the question?) Or do you want to achieve something else?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I want to have autologin for an image created by Yocto. As I have created the image using ubuntu, I mentioned it.

Comment: No problem. Which image are you using? core-image-sato, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at `image.bbclass` I see a function called `set_image_autologin()` which looks in `/etc/sysconfig/gpelogin` for a variable `AUTOLOGIN`. I haven't tried this, but try setting `AUTOLOGIN=true`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I couldn't find /etc/sysconfig/gpelogin in the Yocto image I have created. Could you please let me know if you have any idea regarding this. Thanks again.

Comment: Ahh, came across this: http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-core/2014-December/100254.html. Apparently that's GPE specific. Knowing the image you're using would be useful; see @Anders comment above.